# How can I apply hover properties only to the current point not the entire dataset

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Chart.js 2.0 line chart

I need to only show the hover state on the current point, not on the entire data set.

Chart.js documentation has this example, [image]

This is what my chart looks like when I hover on a single point. [image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. When creating the chart you can specify it in the options.

```
options: {
  hover: {
    mode: 'single'
  }
}
```